# Issues with connecting MySQL workbench with 1and1 Web Server MySQL DB

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have paid for a web server at 1and1.
And I decided to use MySQL WorkBench.

It asked for cred. in MySQL Workbench.

Logging in phpMyAdmin I have the following information to use when making mySQL connection code.

- Server: dbxxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com via TCP/IP
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.5.59-0+deb7u1-log - (Debian)
- Protocol version: 10
- User: dboxxxxxxxxx@00.00.00.00
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

In MySQL Workbench

I place Hostname with dbxxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com
And username as dboxxxxxxxxx@00.00.00.00
And store the password in the vault.

when testing the connection I get this message.

> Connecting to MySQL server ...
>
> Unknown MySQL server host 'dbxxxxxxxx.db.1and1.com' (0)

The DB works fine via the website.

I tried keeping username as root, using the username without the '@', but to no avail.

If you have any experience that you can shed light on what I am doing wrong or not paying attention to, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: There first place to stop with such a problem should be the 1and1 support team. Excuse me please if you have already done so

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a shared server, and for security reason they wont allow to access through third party app. If you want to access through third party app you should change your server plan.